# Clear EditText focus when called onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-edittext

when i press back_key on keyboard with EditText, i want to clear focus in EditText (which mean can't enter something. and hide cursor)

here is problem. when i press back-key once. just disappear keyboard.
and i press again, now i can get log from onBackPressed Method.

i want to clear these( keyboard and cursor[meaning is can't enter something] )

please give me some tips.

here is my code,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout mainLayout;

    EditText editText;
    FrameLayout container;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(editText.isFocused()){
            Log.d("onBackPressed", "foo bar!");
            // here is problem. doesn't work when press back-key first-time,
            // meaning is can't get log. only keyboard just disappear.
            // but i want to clear these(keyboard and cursor) at once.
        }

//        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); textView.requestFocus();
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("onClick", "textView");
            }
        });
        container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); container.requestFocus();
        container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("onClick", "container");
            }
        });

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); editText.requestFocus();
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.d("onFocusChange", "hasFocus #" + hasFocus);
                if (view.getId() == R.id.editText && !hasFocus) { // if (!hasFocus) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and simple layout. having EditText, FrameLayout(just will be container) and TextView(shwoing parent's height changed with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"

        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"

        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="textView : layout_alignParentBottom = true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
In your layout add these lines

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Also to hide keyboard add this in onBackPressed():

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textview.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
textview.clearfocus();
```

add this